# Clearing out data if browser reloads using Horizon.io

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, horizon

For testing purposes, I am trying to re-create the situation where a new user enters the website for the first time. So all existing data should be reset. I tried to use the id of the data I wanted to remove using `data.remove(id)` syntax in a `ready()` method but that did not seem to work. How can I clear out all data when the page is reloaded? Do I manually have to remove each data item using `remove` or `removeAll` or is there a simpler way to do sort of a `clear browser history` which will clear all data from previous sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `removeAll`.  There's no equivalent of clearing browser history because multiple users may be able to read and write to the same document depending on your permissions scheme, so it's hard to define a general rule for what should be cleared.

Comment: Okay, but what if I don't know all the ids of the data? Doesn't removeAll require an id to be passed in? Some of the id's are generated by Horizon and it is difficult to track down each one in order to removeAll.

Comment: If the data affects what the user sees when he logs in, you must already be able to retrieve it.  You can retrieve it that way and look at the IDs.